# Is there a way to list every app available in a Github Enterprise installation?

Tags: github

How can I get a complete list of all apps available in my company's Github Enterprise installation.

On github.com there is the marketplace. I cannot find the marketplace for our Github Enterprise. Nor can I find any API.